# After Upgrade to 18.04 I can no longer mark and scroll text

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

Today I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop. 
After customizing everything I have noticed that, whenever I try to mark the text and try to scroll web down with two fingers on touchpad it doesn't scroll the view, when on Ubuntu 16.04 it used to work. Scrolling with 2 fingers without marking a text works, but with it doesn't.
Any solutions?

Greets